# @string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior auto complete is not show

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-appbarlayout

so I follow this tutorial in youtube, but I got stuck at 11:08 minute, I dont know why my @string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior is not show on my activity.xml file

BY the way this is the link youtube:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qxf8yQVkeik&list=PLFRUC61dWGGFqUezKOGzI4403pAjM-jCv&index=14

and plese dont unvote me, if you dont like my question please give me sugestion about this question and and other questions when I make inquiries, for improve skill my question when I make question.

this is my graddle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.simple_fragment_kotlin"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'




    // Android Support Library
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3'
}
```

this is my android.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayoutt xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextColor="#000"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#fff"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayoutt>
```

and I use androidx api 30, in kotlin programing language

Comment: In your src/values folder, you need to have file called String.xml, in this file there is a string called appbar_scrolling_view_behavior?

Comment: What kind of error you are getting? Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: I don't have an error on my code, but some string is missing, in the video tutorial in my answer, the link is inside of my answer, the speaker in the video tutorial doesnt give the string, did you have to see the video tutorial sir

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency in your app level gradle

```
'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02'
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: what the difference of  'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02' and 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3', its same right or no.

Comment: This one is latest, Just try to add this. Then clear and build your project again.